# Нужно повесить событие мыши на тег option JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let fontFamilyFunction = function() {
  let cursive = document.getElementById('cursive');
  cursive.onclick = function() {
    body.style.fontStyle = 'italic'
  };
}
fontFamilyFunction()
```

```html
<select id="selectFontStyle">
  <option value="choose option" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
  <option id="cursive" value="cursive">Cursive</option>
  <option id="fantasy" value="fantasy">Fantasy</option>
  <option id="monospace" value="monospace">Monospace</option>
  <option id="sansSerif" value="sans-serif">Sans-Serif</option>
</select>
```

Есть данный код, вот только я не могу понять в чем проблема, почему код не работает?
При клике должно менять font style всего body.

Comment: Ну, потому что на `<select>` надо добавлять обработчик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let fontFamilyFunction = function() {
  let select = document.getElementById('selectFontStyle');
  select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    if (this.value == "cursive") {
      body.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
    }
  });
}
fontFamilyFunction()
```

```html
<select id="selectFontStyle">
  <option value="choose option" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
  <option id="cursive" value="cursive">Cursive</option>
  <option id="fantasy" value="fantasy">Fantasy</option>
  <option id="monospace" value="monospace">Monospace</option>
  <option id="sansSerif" value="sans-serif">Sans-Serif</option>
</select>
<p>Test</p>
```